# How to provide an example of an object definition in swagger that contains an array as one of its attributes

Tags: swagger, definitions

Referring to the example below, I would like to provide an example of `NamedElementArray` in its definition.  This will require showing an example of an array of `NamedElement` for the `elements` attribute.

How do I do that? I can't find details of how to do this in the swagger specification.

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: "0.0.0"
  title: Example

definitions:
  Identifier:
    type: string
    format: uuid
  NamedElement:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      identifier:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Identifier"
    required:
    - name
    - identifier
    example:
      name: Identifier1
      identifier: ab804529-11d0-4781-a49a-3bbbc40243df
  NamedElementArray:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: 
        type: string
      elements:
        type: array
        minLength: 0
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/NamedElement"
    required:
    - name
    - elements
    example:
      name: Fred
      elements:

paths:
  /elements/{name}:
    get:
      description: |
        Gets `NamedElement` objects, based on the **name** query param.
      parameters:
        -
          name: name
          in: path
          description: Name of element array to return
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns a named element array
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/NamedElementArray"
        default:
          description: Return nothing
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to choose between *high level* examples and *low level* ones.
In Swagger UI, the high level examples precede the local one.

*Full example available on [Swagger Hub](https://swaggerhub.com/api/apihandyman/TestExamples/1.0.0)*

You can define an example on each property (low level):

```
Identifier:
    type: string
    format: uuid
    example: Local UUID example

NamedElement:
    type: object
    properties:
        name:
            type: string
            example: Local identifier example
        identifier:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Identifier"
        required:
            - name
            - identifier

NamedElementArray:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: 
          type: string
          example: Local name example
      elements:
          type: array
          minLength: 0
          items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/NamedElement"
    required:
        - name
        - elements
```

In that case the example will look like this in Swagger UI:

```json
{
  "name": "Local name example",
  "elements": [
    {
      "name": "Local identifier example",
      "identifier": "Local UUID example"
    }
  ]
}
```

But you can also give a full example on high level like you did in your example on `NamedElement`:

```
NamedElementArray:
    type: object
    properties:
        name: 
            type: string
        elements:
            type: array
            minLength: 0
            items:
                $ref: "#/definitions/NamedElement"
    required:
        - name
        - elements
    example:
        name: Fred
        elements:
            - name: Identifier1
              identifier: ab804529-11d0-4781-a49a-3bbbc40243df
            - name: Identifier2
              identifier: zzz4529-11d0-4781-a49a-3bbbc40243df
```

In that case the example will look like this in Swagger UI:

```json
{
  "name": "Fred",
  "elements": [
    {
      "name": "Identifier1",
      "identifier": "ab804529-11d0-4781-a49a-3bbbc40243df"
    },
    {
      "name": "Identifier2",
      "identifier": "zzz4529-11d0-4781-a49a-3bbbc40243df"
    }
  ]
}
```